# Doctrine can't find entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

Doctrine cannot find my entity in `models` folder of project.

Test file:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array("models"), $isDevMode);
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => '',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => '',
);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

try {
    /** @var \models\Vars $repo */
    $repo = $entityManager->getRepository('Vars');
    echo 'success';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

models/Vars:

```
<?php

namespace models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Annotation as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(name="Vars")
 * @ORM\Table(name="vars")
 */
class Vars
{
}
```

Im newbie in php. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I just remove namespace from entity and now all works. But is it correct solution?